# Finding all the roots inside a DiGraph (networkx)

Tags: python, graph, networkx

Assuming I have this code which creates a DiGraph:

```
dict = {1:['a1', 'a2', 'a3'], 2:['a4', 'a5','a7']}
graph = nx.from_dict_of_lists(dict)
digraph = nx.DiGraph(graph)
```

How can I find all the roots in this graph? 
expected output for this graph is [1,2]

If it's is somewhat more convienent to you, I have written the code inside a [google colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Jg0oBkN9wXptzNJUssJXwBJXtHQrBCIz?usp=sharing) where you can see the graph, hope it helps.

EDIT: this is somehow related to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4122390/getting-the-root-head-of-a-digraph-in-networkx-python) the difference is that in that post there was an assumption of that the graph is connected so there is only one root; it's not the case in my example.
Can I 'divide' my graph to connected sub-graphs and then search for a root in each one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you're not quite generating the graph you have in mind with this example, as all existent connections have bidirectional edges. Probably you meant to generate the graph:

```
d = {1:['a1', 'a2', 'a3'], 2:['a4', 'a5','a7']}
G = nx.from_dict_of_lists(d, create_using=nx.DiGraph)
print(graph.edges())
# OutEdgeView([('1', 'a1'), ('1', 'a2'), ('1', 'a3'), ('2', 'a4'), ('2', 'a5'), ('2', 'a7')])
```

Which gives the two component graph:

```
plt.subplots(figsize=(12,6))
nx.draw(G, with_labels=True, node_color='lightblue', node_size=500)
```

[image]

In order to find the root nodes in each component, we first need to generate the induced subgraphs from the existent connected components, for that we have [`Graph.subgraph`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.Graph.subgraph.html). Then, on each subgraph, the root node can be found by searching over all nodes, and keeping the one with an [`in_degree`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.DiGraph.in_degree.html) of `0`.

```
roots = []
for component in nx.weakly_connected_components(G):
    G_sub = G.subgraph(component)
    roots.extend([n for n,d in G_sub.in_degree() if d==0])
```

---

Which gives:

```
print(roots)
# [1, 2]
```

Comment: Why do we need components? Would not scan of in_degree for the whole input graph have same order of complexity with smaller additional constant?

Answer (score 0):

Simplifying @yatu's answer:

```
d = {1:['a1', 'a2', 'a3'], 2:['a4', 'a5','a7']}
G = nx.from_dict_of_lists(d, create_using=nx.DiGraph)
[n for n in g.nodes if g.in_degree(n) == 0]
# [1, 2]
```